# python animation ... passing an argument

Tags: python, animation

I have a simple python animation program that I downloaded. I am changing it around to understand animation calls a little better. This program makes a simple dot move in a circle on the screen. I placed the functions that change the dot's position and animation calls each into a class. That worked ok. Then I put the definition of the figure into a class. That works ok too. This is how it looks,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class FIG:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig=plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line, = self.ax.plot([], [], 'bo', ms=10)
        self.ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
        self.ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
class sD:    
    def simData(self):
        t_max = 100.0
        dt = 0.001
        x = 0.0
        t = 0.0
        while t < t_max:
            x = np.sin(np.pi*t)
            t = t + dt
            y = np.cos(np.pi*t)
            yield x, y
class sP:
    def simPoints(self,simData):
        x, t = simData[0], simData[1]
        f1.line.set_data(t, x)
        return f1.line #line2#, time_text

f1=FIG()
sd=sD()
sp=sP()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f1.fig, sp.simPoints, sd.simData, blit=False,
     interval=10, repeat=True)

plt.show()
```

Now, I want to pass the figure instace as an argument through the animation call. But it does not work, this is the new code that does not work....

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class FIG:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig=plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line, = self.ax.plot([], [], 'bo', ms=10)
        self.ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
        self.ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
class sD:    
    def simData(self):
        t_max = 100.0
        dt = 0.001
        x = 0.0
        t = 0.0
        while t < t_max:
            x = np.sin(np.pi*t)
            t = t + dt
            y = np.cos(np.pi*t)
            yield x, y
class sP:
    def simPoints(self,simData,figg):
        x, t = simData[0], simData[1]
        figg.line.set_data(t, x)
        return figg.line #line2#, time_text

f1=FIG()
sd=sD()
sp=sP()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f1.fig, sp.simPoints, sd.simData, f1, blit=False,
     interval=10, repeat=True)

plt.show()
```

---

The compiler tells me,

```
self._drawn_artists = self._init_func()
AttributeError: FIG instance has no __call__ method
```

Any comments are appreciated.
Thanks